# PHP and PDO - Migrated from MySQL - Not Showing Results or Errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm migrating parts of my code from mySQL over to PDO and I can't seem to see what is wrong with my code.

I've got a try/catch statement and error reporting on, but i'm getting nothing at all.

Can anyone here see what is wrong?

The files that are relevant to this question are:

**db_pdo.php**

```
<?php

// Define connection

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "winestore";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "pass"; 

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

?>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php

require_once ("MiniTemplator.class.php");

function getSearch($tableName, $attributeName) {
    try {
        require ("db_pdo.php");

        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT {$attributeName} FROM {$tableName} ORDER BY {$attributeName}";

        return $db->query($query);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit; 
    }   
}

function generatePage(){
    $t = new MiniTemplator;

    $t->readTemplateFromFile ("search_template.htm");

    $rows = getSearch("region", "region_name");
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $t->setVariable('regionName', $row['region_name']);

        $t->addBlock("regionName");
    }

    $rows = getSearch("grape_variety", "variety");
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $t->setVariable('variety', $row['variety']);

        $t->addBlock("variety");
    }

    $rows = getSearch("wine", "year");
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $t->setVariable('minYear', $row['year']);

        $t->addBlock("minYear");
    }

    $rows = getSearch("wine", "year");
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $t->setVariable('maxYear', $row['year']);

        $t->addBlock("maxYear");
    }
    $t->generateOutput();
}

generatePage();

?>
```

Comment: you dint return anything in function generatePage(){

Comment: @punithasubramaniv it can be assumed that output is handled by `$t->generateOutput()`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing in `$rows`, but you are using `$result` afterwards, which will be empty.

```
// $rows = getSearch("region", "region_name");
// should be this:
$result = getSearch("region", "region_name");
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Side note: You are creating a new database connection with every search. You should store your `$db` object and reuse it, instead of creating new instances of it. I'd recommend to wrap all these functions in a class where you store it, but since you stated that you are migrating existing code you could use `global $db` to pull the existing object into the variable scope of your function:

```
// include this file once at the beginning of your script
require_once("db_pdo.php");

function getSearch($tableName, $attributeName) {
  global $db; // pull $db inside the variable scope
  try {
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew I had made a rookie mistake somewhere along the transition! 

As for the class, I will look into that! Could you point me in the direction of some documentation for your last point (using global $db)?

Comment: Thank you very much! Works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Try it?

```
$rows = getSearch("region", "region_name");
```

but

```
$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_$rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ )){
```

to

```
$rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Comment: Your solution is correct as well! I was storing in a variable that wasn't called. 

Thanks for your input!